# AutoSuggest component in standard JSF 2.0 component set

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, autosuggest

Is there a Google-like autosuggest input component in standard JSF 2.0 component set?

Answer (score 3):

The [standard JSF `<h:xxx>` component set](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) doesn't have such a component. All it offers are just basic HTML elements. An autosuggest field is basically a combination of an `<input type="text">` and an `<ul><li>` of items which is created and positioned by JavaScript and filled by Ajax and styled by a good shot by CSS. This is not a single basic HTML element.

Implementing your own isn't exactly trivial if you're new to JSF. Simplest would be to create a [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) with a `<h:inputText>` and add the necessary JS/CSS code yourself. Fortunately, there exist JSF component libraries which adds *just* that extra on top of the standard JSF components and often already provides such a component out the box. For example:

- [RichFaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces): [`<rich:autocomplete>`](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=autocomplete&skin=blueSky)
- [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org): [`<p:autoComplete>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml)
- [OpenFaces](http://openfaces.org): [`<o:suggestionField>`](http://openfaces.org/demo/suggestionfield/SuggestionField.jsf)
- [IceFaces](http://icefaces.org): [`<ice:selectInputText>`](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface)

<sup>*(note: all tags above are clickable and show you the online demo)*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to add a component library to your JSF project, you could instead integrate the jQuery autocomplete widget.  This is a client-side JavaScript solution which is agnostic to the server-side technology.  Adding this widget will therefore have little on no impact on your server-side code.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/